# MsSQL LEFT JOIN with double GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying currently using MsSQL for a product shipping DB. I have spent a long time trying to write a SQL query to get the amount of products going to each delivery location in an area, per date, in a 4 day period beginning today.
In an area means that there is another location that is parent to that location.

The tables concerned are Products and Locations and are structured as follows

```
Products    
ProductID  DeliveryDate  DestinationID
1          2018-10-05    1
2          2018-10-05    2
3          2018-10-05    3
4          2018-10-06    1
5          2018-10-06    5

Locations
LocationID  OwnerID     
1           4
2           4
3           4
4           Null
5           6
6           Null
```

The output desired is as follows

```
DeliveryDate  Destination ProductCount
2018-10-04    1           Null
2018-10-04    2           Null
2018-10-04    3           Null
2018-10-05    1           1
2018-10-05    2           1
2018-10-05    3           1 
2018-10-06    1           1
2018-10-06    2           Null
2018-10-06    3           Null
2018-10-07    1           Null
2018-10-07    2           Null
2018-10-07    3           Null
```

What I have tried so far is this

```
DECLARE @startdate DATETIME
    ,@enddate DATETIME

SET @startdate = convert(varchar, '2018-10-04 00:00:00', 102)
SET @enddate = convert(varchar, '2018-10-07 00:00:00', 102)

;WITH DateArray
AS (
    SELECT @startdate DateVal

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DateVal + 1
    FROM DateArray
    WHERE DateVal + 1 <= @enddate
    )
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT da.DateVal AS DeliveryDate
FROM DateArray da) a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ISNULL(COUNT(p.ProductID),0) AS ProductCount,
        DeliveryDate,
        ISNULL(p.DestinationID,'') AS Destination
FROM Product p
AND p.DestinationID IN(SELECT LocationID FROM Locations WHERE OwnerID = 4)
GROUP BY p.DestinationID, p.DeliveryDate) AS b
ON b.DeliveryDate = a.DeliveryDate
```

The result ensures that all dates are present even if the ProductCount is null, however, not every Destination is shown if count is null. Shown below:

```
DeliveryDate  Destination  ProductCount
2018-10-04    Null        Null
2018-10-05    1           1
2018-10-05    2           1
2018-10-05    3           1 
2018-10-06    1           1
2018-10-07    Null        Null
```

I have spent two days stubbornly trying to figure this out with many online SQL resources and scouring StackOverFlow but with no luck.

Comment: Your subquery doesn't have "WHERE"

Comment: why does locationid = 5 not appear in your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend creating a numbers table or a calendar table, but you recursive query suffices for small sets.

```
DECLARE
  @startdate DATETIME = '2018-10-04 00:00:00',
  @enddate   DATETIME = '2018-10-07 00:00:00';

WITH
  DateArray AS
(
  SELECT @startdate DateVal
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DateVal + 1 FROM DateArray WHERE DateVal + 1 <= @enddate
)
SELECT
  DateArray.DateVal          AS DeliveryDate,
  Locations.LocationID       AS Destination,
  COUNT(Products.ProductID)  AS ProductCount
FROM
  DateArray
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE OwnerID = 4
)
  Locations
LEFT JOIN
  Products
    ON  Products.DeliveryDate  = DateArray.DateVal
    AND Products.DestinationID = Locations.LocationID
GROUP BY
  DateArray.DateVal,
  Locations.LocationID
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  DateArray.DateVal          AS DeliveryDate,
  Locations.LocationID       AS Destination,
  Products.ProductCount      AS ProductCount
FROM
  DateArray
CROSS JOIN
(
  SELECT * FROM Locations WHERE OwnerID = 4
)
  Locations
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT DeliveryDate, DestinationID, COUNT(*) AS ProductCount
    FROM Products
GROUP BY DeliveryDate, DestinationID
)
  Products
    ON  Products.DeliveryDate  = DateArray.DateVal
    AND Products.DestinationID = Locations.LocationID
```